# How to code keyword to trigger basic python speech recognition

Tags: python, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, google-speech-api, google-speech-to-text-api

I am currently following the Real_Python guide on the SpeechRecognition package, and I have completed it with success, but my use case isn't covered in the tutorial, as I am trying to make an assistant similar to Alexa, or Siri, but much more basic. I am not able to get it to start recognizing as I say a keyword. However, I am unsure of where to start with this. Here is what I have so far:

```
r = sr.Recognizer()
file = sr.AudioFile('C:\PP\CodingTrash\chill.wav')
mic = sr.Microphone()
r.dynamic_energy_threshold = True
with mic as source:
    r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
    audio = r.listen(source)
text = r.recognize_google(audio)
print(text)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

if you are good to go with google then you may try with google cloud, then is a bunch of things on the internet for google cloud in python integration or you can prefer code with harry's youtube channel regarding speech recognition with pyttsx3.

Comment: answer is totally different